# Неточность в разметке xml

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, какой атрибут или что надо добавить, чтобы `TextView` был на всю ширину, как показано красными стрелками?

Тут идея в том, что ширина `wrap_content` у `RelativeLayout` определяется маскимальной шириной либо `TextView`, либо `RadioButton`, но надо сделать так, что если `RadioButton` шире `TextView`, то `TextView` надо растягивать до конца границ `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="18dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#3f4d61">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="17dp"
        android:paddingRight="17dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#c9ccde"
        android:text="Выбрать язык"
        android:background="#fa172a41"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            android:buttonTint="#8a9cb1"
            android:textColor="#c5cae9"
            android:text="Russian abcdefghijklmno"
            android:layoutDirection="ltr"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>
    </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тогда он растягивает на всю ширину экрана, а надо чтобы TextView растянулся до ширины RelativeLayout. Вы прежде чем минусить, попробуйте этот код в андроид студии и внимательно читайте вопрос.. Надеюсь вам минус поставят..

Comment: Попробуйте дать привязки к краям контейнера, ака `android:layout_alignParentLeft/Right` с шириной в `0dp` и другими вариантами. А это у вас макет для диалога? Тогда может лучше дать всем `math_parent`? Хотя, наверное, у диалогов окно подгоняется к макету, а не наоборот. Тогда задать конкретный размер в `dp` контейнеру и растянуть всех по `math_parent`. Размер определить в `dimen` ресурсе с альтернативами по размерам экранов, или найти стандартный ресурс ширины диалога. Ещё вариант: использовать стандартный диалог с заголовком и списком, а оформление ему задать в стилях

Comment: С привязками тоже растягивается на всю ширину.. Да пока просто без всяких диалоговых окон, вот такую задачу как я поставил, она в принципе простыми атрибутами не решается что ли?

Comment: Проблема в том, что у вас ширина всех трёх зависит друг от друга и расчёт путается. Нужно дать хотя бы одному элементу размер, не зависимый от других. И, кстати, `RelativeLayout` на устройстве может настроиться не так как в превью в подобных неоднозначных ситуациях.

Comment: то, что вы хотите, видимо нельзя решить никакими атрибутами в разметке, потому что при инфлейте виджетов сначала будет создан первый в иерархии разметки, затем второй и первый уже не будет пересчитываться еще раз, если его размер нужно изменить (подогнать под второй) дерево виджетов просканировано и второго прохода не будет. вам нужно выбрать один опорный виджет, от которого будет рассчитан размер другого или рассчитывать их размеры программно и добавлять в разметку через код.

Comment: На основе ответов пришел к выводу, что надо либо дать фиксированный размер контейнеру, либо все высчитывать программно ширину. Вопрос к модераторам, человек сначала дал неправильный ответ(вариант с match_parent, "если бы так просто было") не разобравшись даже с сутью вопроса, поставил он или не он мне минус, потом ответ удалил.. Как-то не правильно это наверно, вроде суть вопроса не самая тривиальная, и легких решений автоматической подгонки контейнера под заданные условия нет..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте для фона отдельный элемент. С RelativeLayout не получится, его будет растягивать до match_parent. На ConstraintLayout так:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="18dp"
    android:background="#3f4d61"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#fa172a41"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="17dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="17dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        tools:text="Выберите язык"
        android:textColor="#c9ccde"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:buttonTint="#8a9cb1"
            tools:text="Russian"
            android:textColor="#c5cae9" />
    </RadioGroup>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде работает! По началу tools:text= не заметил, думал не работает, заменил на android:text и все в порядке стало на первый взгляд.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы это делал в `ConstraintLayout` с заданным параметром `android:minWidth`
Мой пример:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="18dp"
    android:background="#3f4d61"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#fa172a41"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="17dp"
        android:paddingRight="17dp"
        android:text="Выбрать язык"
        android:textColor="#c9ccde"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/radioGroup"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/radioGroup"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/radioGroup"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="40dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:buttonTint="#8a9cb1"
            android:text="Russian abcdefghijklmno"
            android:textColor="#c5cae9" />
    </RadioGroup>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Поясню. Главный слой зависит от внутренних элементов. `RadioGroup` прикреплен к краям слоя и имеет минимальную ширину `android:minWidth="200dp"`.
`TextView` привязан по ширине к границам `RadioGroup` и имеет ширину `math_constraint`, т.е. будет занимать всю доступную область. Несколько скриншотов из студии:
[image: пример1]
[image: пример2]

Comment: Спасибо, похоже, но правда надо знать минимальную ширину. Ну как-нибудь сделаю, варианты есть. Чисто автоматически не получится все равно, выше есть объяснения. Смертельной необходимости в этом нет, просто захотелось вот такой дизайн и задался вопросом, вдруг какие хитрости или финты существуют для такой реализации)